# Change route parameter key in Laravel resource route definition for the only update method

Tags: laravel-9

I use resource route like this

```
Route::resource('article', \App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class);
```

and i get these routes

```
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/create 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/inValidate/{article}
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/validate/{article}
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article} 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article} 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article} 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article}/edit
```

I want to only change the update method key to {dashboard_article_update}
like this:

```
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/create 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/inValidate/{article}
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/validate/{article}
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article} 

dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{dashboard_article_update} -------

dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article} 
dashboard.khassepaz.test/article/{article}/edit
```

is there any way to do that with just a resource route definition?

I tried this but it does not work.

```
Route::resource('article', \App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, [
    'update' => ['params' => ['article' => 'dashboard_article_show']]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take use of Laravel's [Partial Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes)

When declaring a resource route, you may specify a subset of actions the controller should handle instead of the full set of default actions

```php
Route::resource('article', ArticleController::class)->except([
    'create', 'store', 'destroy', //...
]);
```

and create a dedicated update route

```php
Route::put('/article/{dashboard_article_show}', [ArticleController::class, 'update']);
```

Comment: I know this way. But my question was not about the dedicated method of defining the root. Like put or get, I just want to change the key inside the resource definition. @lordisp

Comment: For all routes of the resource or just the one you mentioned in the question? I understood you like to change this for one of the default routes the resource generated.

Comment: Correct. I want to change only one route of default routes the resource generated but I don't want to use another static methods or "except" or "only" @lordisp

Comment: This is the path to follow. To the best of my knowledge, this is the sole method to achieve your requirements.